# iOS build distribution through Appcenter

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to distribute my `Xamarin Forms` `iOS` app through `Visual Studio App Centre`. I am using a `In-House Certificate` for the same but the app is not getting installed. Does App Centre supports distribution on `In-House Certificates`.

Comment: By In-house, do you mean "Apple Enterprise Developer Program"? If so, does the user have your "distribution provisioning profile" installed?

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes

Comment: Can you give more info about your setup? Is it distribution certificate, profile? In AppCenter have you setup the release build with correct p12, password and profile? Any error popup while installing? Is it installed and greyed out?